# Rhythmbox plugins installation dependency issue

Tags: rhythmbox

I tried to install plug-ins in Rhytmbox Music player but I get this error http://prntscr.com/5ecetc.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly: Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.4 is to be installed
                           Depends: libdvdread4 (>= 4.1.3) but 4.2.1-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.37.3) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: liborc-0.4-0 (>= 1:0.4.18) but 1:0.4.18-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a terminal,type

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the `-f` flag means `--fix-missing`

after this, u can run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

this installs a few third-party plugins.

You can try to run your plugin install command again.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. In this situation you just need to install these plug-ins with Terminal.

```
# sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

# sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3
```

Comment: This has worked for me , but for your information I followed the femurs answer before doing this.